# Schedule Local Notification on second Tuesday From Now at Specific Time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have to Schedule local notification from now to 2nd tuesday, 3rd friday etc.So please specify that how do I get the FireDate. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get next week's Tuesday using `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar`. I hope this helps

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekday|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:now];

    components.weekday = 3; //Tuesday on Gregorian calendar
    components.weekOfYear += 1; //next week
    NSDate *endDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

`endDate` here would be your `fireDate` of the local notification. For further help on this, you can read `NSDateComponents` documentation. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm sorry if the code doesn't work, I just posted to give you the overall understanding how to achieve your goal, don't have time to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; 
NSDateComponents *c = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];


[c setYear:2012];
[c setWeekday:3]; //1 for Sunday 2 for monday 3 for Tuesday
[c setWeekdayOrdinal:2]; // The 2rd Tuesday

for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
     [c setMonth:i];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:c];
NSLog(@"Date[%i]: %@",i,date);  
}
```

From this you will get the date of Tuesday for every month. Then you register your local notification on passing time like you want to show notification after 1 hours so Use

```
 NSDate *firedate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:1*60*60 sinceDate:tuesdayDate];
```